# how can new line code be found from file by grep command on mac?

Tags: macos, command-line

I have data as below

`data1,
data2,data3
data4,data5
data6,`

And I want to count number of line which ends by `,`
From example data, I expect it returns 2.

Though I'm using command `grep -c ",\n" data.csv`, it doesn't return as I expect.
How can I manage this by command on Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dollar sign to match an end-of-line pattern.

```
grep -c ",$" data.csv
```